# How to calculate yxy rotation sequence given the quaternion transformation and how to interpret data

Tags: matlab, rotation, sensors, quaternions

**Still need the math: I am trying to calculate the yxy rotation sequence given a quaternion transformation.  I can easily do this using Matlab's quat2angle function.  However, I need to calculate this by hand using a python script.**

*This part solved:  Please look at this awesome presentation which helped me resolve these issues below:*
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.udel.edu%2Fbiology%2Frosewc%2Fkaap686%2Freserve%2Fshoulder%2Fshoulder%2FBluePresentation.ppt&ei=jgRAVLHfOsSrogTJiYHABQ&usg=AFQjCNGFmwh11jEZen80jc3tM4f7HUQcNw&sig2=Dlr8_7TIFPLyUfJy6-pSJA&bvm=bv.77648437,d.cGU

Also, with Matlab, I am seeing strange results with the way they calculate yxy.  I have a quaternion transformation of [1.0000 -0.0002 -0.0011 -0.0006] and I get y = 112.4291 x = -0.0719 y1 = -112.5506 (in degrees).

I don't expect to see any rotations here (my sensors aren't rotating).  Why is Matlab showing me rotation?  And when I try to just move in the x rotation, I see y and y1 also rotate, however, I don't expect y or y1 to be rotating.  Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
When I add y + y1 I seem to get the value for the first y (when doing simple rotation around the first y), and this smooths out the data.  However, when I combine the three rotations of the shoulder, the data doesn't make sense. I am trying to define shoulder movement based on plane of elevation, elevation and rotation (yxy) in a way that's easy to interpret.  When I rotate around x, then the second y, I get "clipping" (data goes to 180 then -180 following positive trend for y1 and opposite happens for y), even though I start my sensors at the zero position.  Also, If I try to rotate only around the second y, I see rotation in the x.  That doesn't make any sense either.  Any additional thoughts?

Note:
I am using 2 IMU sensors, taring them in the same orientation, holding one constant and rotating the other, calculating the relative rotation between them using quaternions, and then calculating the yxy rotation sequence angles.

Comment: That yxy result is pretty close to no rotation.  Notice the +y followed by the -y of almost the same magnitude.  Watch out for quaternion conventions.  Sometimes the "w" component is specified first, sometimes last.

Comment: Hi Peter. Yes you are right. Thanks. Please read my update and see if you can add more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested in quaternion calculations and transformations.  I solved it using this transformations library:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/transformations.py.html

There are several functions in here using matrices, quaternions, and Euler rotations.  And you can convert quaternions to several different Euler rotation sequences.  Give thanks to the person who created this script.